# Python logging handler ignored in submodules

Tags: python, logging

## situation

I got my logging handler configured like this in my `main.py`

```
logger = logging.getLogger("__name__")
fh = logging.FileHandler("./log/error.log")
fh.setLevel(logging.WARN)
logger.addHandler(fh)
```

From my `main.py` I'm calling some `@staticmethod` in a submodule `sub.py`. Because these are static, in every method at the beginning I get the logger of my `main.py` using `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` *(maybe you know a better way to grab that logger? Currently this is breaking `DRY` imho)*.

## issue

when I log something in my `main.py` using e.g. `logger.error("something went wrong")` then it will be saved in my `error.log` file just as I configured it. It will *not* be send to console, just as I want it. **But** when I do the same logging call from my `sub.py` method it is send to console (stderr) in addition, which is not what I want.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error level printing to console is the default configuration so main.py isn't configuring your logger.

That's because main.py is configuring a logger literally named "_*name*_". Sub is configuring a logger named "main.sub" (Assuming a basic package structure and you execute main.py).

### The Fix

Quickest fix is to update this line in main.py:

```
logger = logging.getLogger("main")
```

Calls to logger main.sub will bubble up to logger main and get caught by it's handler.

### Take away

You may still want to use __name__ in main.py because you've read it's good practice. That's only the case for modules called by other modules. Here's what to keep in mind:

Strings stay strings so if calling main.py or sub.py:

```
print('__name__')  # '__name__'
```

If you run *python main.py*:

```
import sub
print(__name__)  # '__main__'
print(sub.__name__)  # 'main.sub'
```

If you run *python sub.py*:

```
import main
print(main.__name__)  # 'main'
print(__name__)  # '__main__'
```

Comment: Okay so I was testing this and it's partly true. When I explicitly set the logger to a string, let's say `logger = logging.getLogger("main")` **everywhere** then this works. However when I set it to `logger = logging.getLogger("__name__")` in my `main.py` and `logger = logging.getLogger("main")` in my `sub.py` then I'm still running into that issue. In my log I can see: `ERROR:main:some error message from sub.py
ERROR:__name__:some error message from main.py`. So, I guess `__name__` is not resolving for some reason...

Comment: I was using `logger = logging.getLogger("__name__")` instead of `logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)` and this lead to the error. Thought I was sure I saw `"__name__"` syntax in other examples. However: it's working now. Thanks!

Comment: Also, I had to use `logger = logging.getLogger("__main__")` in my `sub.py`

Comment: Try getLogger("main") in main.py and getLogger(__name__) in sub.py. That'll be closer to what's generally expected. "__main__" is not good practice.

Comment: yes, but for some reason that wouldn't work. I checked it with `__name__` and it returned `"__main__"` not `"main"`

Comment: Ahh, your calling sub.py from the cli. Yeah, go woth "main" everywhere instead of "\_\_main\_\_". The dunder makes it look like your calling a reserved word when it's just a regular string